# Add each item values of dataframe in a list R

Tags: r

I have one list with a series of dataframes. I want to add the values of these data frames based on each cell. Please suggest me how to do that..

```
> df
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
A  4  7  4  4  6  5
C  4  1  6  6  2  3
G  3  3  1  2  2  5
T  5  5  5  3  5  2

[[3]]
  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
A  8  2  5  4  7  6
C  4  7  4  6  3  4
G  3  8  4  8  5  6
T  7  5  9  3  6  5
```

The result should ignore first list item and add C1 values of [[2]] with [[3]], C2 values of [[2]] with [[3]] and so on.. Result should be produced in one DF with values like

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6
A   12  9   9   8   13  11
C   8   8   10  12  5   7
G   6   11  5   10  7   11
T   12  10  14  6   11  7
```

The main list will contain 100+ dataframes all with equal dimension. Please help me and suggest a better way of doing this without loop.

Thanks
Tanmay

Answer (score 0):

We can extract the `list` elements with `[[` and do a `+`

```
df[[2]] + df[[3]]
#  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
#A 12  9  9  8 13 11
#C  8  8 10 12  5  7
#G  6 11  5 10  7 11
#T 12 10 14  6 11  7
```

If there are multiple elements, keep it in a `list` and use `Reduce` with `+`

```
Reduce(`+`, df[-1])
```

Comment: Is there any way to use any list operation to add values of elements of it?

Comment: @Tanmay It is not clear about your request.  Perhaps `Reduce('+', df[-1], accumulate = TRUE)`